# React with Webpack not displaying errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack-dev-server

I'm running react with HMR using webpack. When a function is deleted in a server or used shared service is deleted, no errors are emitted, neither in the console nor on the terminal.
This error can not be seen even during the build process.

I've waisted at least a day trying to find a solution for it. Any help is appreciated.

thank you.

```
const DEV_SERVER = {
    contentBase: PATHS.public,
    hot: true,
    open: true,
    hotOnly: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    overlay: true,
    port: 3000,
// stats: 'verbose',
// proxy: {
//   '/api': 'http://localhost:8888'
// },
```

**More Details**

if i have `user.service.ts` imported in an `index.ts` file and use in all the other files, then i delete the user.service.ts file.

**Expected Behaviour**: An error with module not found.

**Current Behaviour**: Nothing is showing in the console or terminal.

React v 16.13

Webpack v 4.41

Comment: Do you mean changing the HMR (webpack) server?

Comment: i want to keep using the hmr, but also emit errors if a shared and used file is deleted, or some code got deleted by accident.

Comment: Do you mean client-side code? - If not, you can run two instances of webpack (one for the server and one for the client)

Comment: only client side. The issue happens when i delete or change a file name which is already used, i don't get any errors in react neither in the console nor in the terminal. I assume that webpack is ignoring the change

Comment: i added more details to the question @EliasSchablowski

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the error-overlay-webpack-plugin?

```
const ErrorOverlayPlugin = require("error-overlay-webpack-plugin");

module.exports =  {
    plugins: [new ErrorOverlayPlugin()]
);
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/error-overlay-webpack-plugin

Comment: i know this library but it have no effect on this issue.

Comment: Also, don't use `eval-*` as your `devtool` or it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Check the source maps used, this worked for me:

```
devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map'
```

Comment: tried that still not working, i ended by creating a new project and setting up new webpack configs and the issue seems to be fixed.

Comment: Confirmed: Using `eval-*` as a `devtool` option prevents `react-error-overlay` from hooking into runtime errors.